# __InstanceModificationEvent class in c#

Tags: c#, wmi

I am  trying to use __InstanceModificationEvent class on a a WMI query so that when size of usb change, this event kicks in. However, this doesn't do anything. Could you please provide me with tips on how to use __InstanceModificationEvent class?

```
SELECT * 
FROM __InstanceModificationEvent 
WITHIN 2 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Diskdrive' 
    and TargetInstance.Interfacetype = 'USB'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) to easily create a watcher.

1) Define your class:

```
[WMIClass("__InstanceModificationEvent")]
public class ModificationEvent
{
    public string TargetInstance { get; set; }

    [WMIProperty("TIME_CREATED")]
    public long Time { get; set; }
}
```

2) Then create watcher and start handling events:

```
WMIWatcher watcher = new WMIWatcher("root\\CimV2", "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Diskdrive' and TargetInstance.Interfacetype = 'USB'", typeof(ModificationEvent));
watcher.WMIEventArrived += Watcher_WMIEventArrived;

private static void Watcher_WMIEventArrived(object sender, WMIEventArgs e)
{
    ModificationEvent yourEvent = (ModificationEvent)e.Object;

    Console.Log(yourEvent.TargetInstance);
}
```

Comment: where do i write code so it trigger when the size of usb change. I am trying to see if i could time_create to trigger when the size of total usb changes. Thanks